# Golang stdin reads german umlauts wrong

Tags: go, character-encoding

I'm from germany so I use umlauts like `ä`, `ö` and `ü`. Golang however doesn't read them correctly from stdin.

When I execute this simple program:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    for {
        b, _, _ := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadLine()
        printBytes(b)
    }

}

func printBytes(bytes []byte) {
    for _, b := range bytes {
        fmt.Printf("0x%X ", b)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

I get the output:

```
C:\dev\golang>go run test.go
ä
0xE2 0x80 0x9E
```

`E2 80 9E` isn't the correct byte sequence for the `ä` in UTF-8 ([this tool](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=E2+80+9E&mode=bytes) tells me it's an "DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK" -> `„`) and when I just print out what I've read it prints `"`. I've written a small "hack" which seems to read the characters correct:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * getline(void) {
    char * line = malloc(100), * linep = line;
    size_t lenmax = 100, len = lenmax;
    int c;

    if(line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for(;;) {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
        if(c == EOF)
            break;

        if(--len == 0) {
            len = lenmax;
            char * linen = realloc(linep, lenmax *= 2);

            if(linen == NULL) {
                free(linep);
                return NULL;
            }
            line = linen + (line - linep);
            linep = linen;
        }

        if((*line++ = c) == '\n')
            break;
    }
    *line = '\0';
    return linep;
}

void freeline(char* ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

func getLineFromCp850() string {
    line := C.getline()
    goline := C.GoString(line)
    C.freeline(line)
    b := []byte(goline)
    ub, _ := charmap.CodePage850.NewDecoder().Bytes(b)
    return string(ub)
}

func main() {
    for {
        line := getLineFromCp850()
        printBytes([]byte(line))
    }

}

func printBytes(bytes []byte) {
    for _, b := range bytes {
        fmt.Printf("0x%X ", b)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

And it prints out:

```
C:\dev\golang>go run test.go
ä
0xC3 0xA4 0xA
```

`C3 A4` is the correct bytesequence for the `ä` (0A is the linefeed which my hack doesn't strip) so it seems like, reading and converting from CP850 to UTF-8 does the job, as I expected, but why does Go give me gibberish when I read the line using Go's functionality instead of cgo? Whats wrong with Go that it gives me those values, doesn't it interpret the input bytes as CP850 but another charset? Is there a better Go-only way to handle this problem?

This problem only arises when **reading** from stdin. When I print out a UTF-8 `ä` to stdout it prints correctly in the console.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question? Go assumes UTF8 by default, and you're inputting CP850

Comment: Go assumes UTF-8 for strings in its source-code but if run from the terminal (cmd.exe) shouldn't it read stdin correctly and convert from the terminals codepage to UTF-8? Even if Go expects UTF-8 from the console, this doesn't explain why I get a completely unrelated UTF-8 character and not just the error-rune. Even if I read bytes directly from stdin I receive these three bytes, which the console __definitely__ doesn't send as my C function correctly receives the CP850 value for the `ä`.

Comment: [I created an Issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16857) as Golang interprets the input as codepage 1252 instead of 850 even though the console uses 850.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was a bug in Golang for some systems, to be specific for Windows systems where the overall used charset and the console charset were different (Where `GetACP()` and `GetConsoleCP()` from WinAPI returned different things). In Germany, for example, (and maybe other west-european countries), Windows uses the codepage 1252 as the overall-charset but it uses codepage 850 for the console `cmd.exe`. Not sure why, but thats how it is. Golang wrongly used `GetACP()` to decode the input to UTF-8 when it really should've used the codepage returned by `GetConsoleCP()`. We found the problem in the [Issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16857) I created and we'll hopefully see the fix merged for the next version of Golang.

We also found a problem on Windows where Golang decoded characters to *decomposed UTF-8* characters (i.e. it would read a `ä` to the character `a` followed by the COMBINING DIAERESIS `̈`) which could lead to other problems, for example printing those decomposed characters prints them separate instead of one combined character.